# FoxPro and VB6 - Calling functions

Tags: vb6, foxpro

I am building an application (in vb6) that uses data from a third party application (written in foxpro)
The problem is that the foxpro program has a function to calculate taxes, and, its logic is complex enough
for writing it again in vb6. Plus, if the function changes in the future, I do not want to write fix the vb6.
What I need to do is, somehow, call this foxpro function from the vb6 program, and get it results.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you can call it that way depends on the FoxPro program. If it has a COM object you can instantiate, you have one option. Alternatively, if the application lets you pass parameters in to tell it what you want, that's another possibility.

Is this an off-the-shelf application or a custom application? In other words, do you have source and the possibility of modifying it?

Tamar

Comment: No, it is not a COM object (and, as I know very little about Fox, I don't want to turn it in one!)
Yes, I do have the source... I have some issues for compiling it because it is developed in VFP5 (an I only have the VFP6 CD) so, the question was if I could do something without modifiying the original.

Anyway, what ideas do you have that INVOLVES modifiying the original source?

Comment: If you need just one function from the original, you might build it into an EXE by itself with appropriate parameters. You could then call the EXE from your VB program, passing the right parameters.